# How to make a character/special character mandatory in a string using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, url

**Requirement**: String should have one or more . (dot) in middle of the string.

**Example** :

```
      "abccom"      false
      ".abc.com"    false
      "abccom."     false
      "abc:.com"    false
      "abc..com"    false

      "a2b.com"     true
      "abc.com"     true
      "ab.cc.in"    true
```

**Tried**:

```
var regex = /^[a-z0-9]+(.[a-z]+)?$/;
regex.test("abccom")  // Output : true
```

Explain a bit about how to make a particular character mandatory or relevant link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^\w+(\.\w+)+$/
```

All characters are mandatory, unless explicitly marked as not mandatory (using `?` or `*`).

Your problem is that you need to escape the `.` as `\.`, because `.` is a special character that will match any character. You can also use `\w` to match common 'word' characters.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions) for details on all of the special characters in RegExp.

Comment: Sorry for all the edits, the mobile app doesn't let you read the question while you answer, and I'm bad at reading apparently...